# Fail2ban with apache filter for 40*-hits

Tags: apache, ubuntu, http-status-code-404, fail2ban

i update my fail2ban from 0.9.x to 0.10.x

And after that my custom filter doesn´t work anymore
The function with this filter is that is ban ip after 4 hits on 404-page ( page not found ) on apache

I found a problem in failregex.

```
2018-08-22 15:45:32,440 fail2ban.transmitter    [23452]: WARNING Command ['set', 'apache-40', 'addfailregex', '(?P<host>[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}) .+ 4[0-9]{1,2} [0-9]+ "'] has failed. Received RegexException('No failure-id group in \'(?P<host>[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}) .+ 4[0-9]{1,2} [0-9]+ "\'',)
    2018-08-22 15:45:32,440 fail2ban                [23452]: ERROR   NOK: ('No failure-id group in \'(?P<host>[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}) .+ 4[0-9]{1,2} [0-9]+ "\'',)
```

In this post i found something about that i need to add a new string beacuse ip6-support
https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/issues/2130#issuecomment-391680328

my originalfile is this

```
[Definition]
failregex = (?P<host>[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}) .+ 4[0-9]{1,2} [0-9]+ "
ignoreregex = favicon\.ico
```

Any suggestion gor the new string ?

Comment: `<HOST>` is there for failregex's to match IP address so you don't need to write your own. Additionally your "regex" is susceptible to DoS attacks. Honestly don't waste your CPU on banning 404 messages, its just just background noise. If you don't like seeing them, configure locations that don't log. Using fail2ban to reduce weblogs isn't actually providing a security benefit. You're just burning though CPU, especially with your regexes, and taking that away from your legitimate users.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend configuring apache to not log anything around these locations that you frequently get 404 message on. That way the CPU and disk IO saved writing the logs can be used for your real visitors.

CPU/IO time is also saved when you don't need fail2ban to scan through the logs.

Every real visitor is saved from being subject to IP/nftables rules slowing down their access.

You'll also be saved the anguish of looking at the logs and focusing on the background noise of the internet rather than the real visitors you care about.